# Html/css: Put elements behind a repeating background

Tags: html, css, background-image, repeat

I am trying to find a way to put a nav bar behind some background images that repeat. Here it is:
[image]

Basically, I want to have a navigation bar behind the repeating plants image, but in front of the sun image. I am going to make the nav elements popup when they are hovered over. Here is my css for the header:

```
header {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("top.png"), url("banner.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x, no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 40px, cover;
  background-position: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Need more code here (preferably a working snippet). If you're using multiple bg images on the same element, you probably can't accomplish what you're trying to. You'll probably need to put those on different elements.

Comment: So I would need to have 2 overlapping elements, each with their own background and z-indexes?

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing a more complete example of what you have.

Comment: I really don't have a lot yet. Here is my webpage: http://pastebin.com/EGMssRsw I put it all in on html file for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the solution was to use z-index as Howzieky mentioned but did not provide an example for. Here is how I did it:

css:

```
header {
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#background-far {
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("banner.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}

#header-body {
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#background-close {
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("top.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: auto 40px;
    background-position: bottom;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

html:

```
<header>
    <div id="background-far"></div>
    <div id="header-body">
        <img src="logo.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="background-close"></div>
</header>
```

I also needed split the header into 3 sections (background-far, header-body and background-close). Header body will store everything I will have in the header such as my nav bar. The important part was to make the header use `position: relative` and each section to use `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;`

Thanks for all your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [`z-index`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). From W3Schools:

"The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order."

The larger the `z-index` of an element, the closer to the front the element is.

Comment: How do I assign different z-index's for different background images like I have in my code? Or should I do it a different way?

Comment: You can't. This is an incomplete "answer" that wasn't given with your code example in mind. You can control the stacking order of multiple backgrounds, but that won't help for your use case. 
https://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: There are three basic ways to do this. Pure HTML: `<*ELEMENT* style="z-index:*INDEX*">`. Pure CSS: `*ELEMENT* {z-index:*INDEX*}`. Pure Javascript: `document.getElementById(*ELEMENTID*).style.zIndex = *INDEX*`